# Can SQL CASE return a different number of columns in WHEN clauses?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Is there a way to `SELECT` a different number of columns in different `WHEN` clauses of the same `CASE` statement?

For example

```
SELECT
  CASE x
    WHEN is y THEN show me 1 column
    WHEN is z THEN show me 3 columns
  END
  FROM i;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction is that all branches of the `CASE` expression must resolve to the **same data type**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

> The data types of all the ***result*** expressions must be convertible to a
>   single output type. See [Section 10.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-union-case.html) for more details.

***If*** all your output columns have a compatible data type, you could use an ARRAY to include a variable number of columns (resulting in the same array type). Like:

```
SELECT CASE x
         WHEN 1 THEN ARRAY[y]
         WHEN 2 THEN ARRAY[x,y,z]
         -- no ELSE defaults to NULL
       END AS my_result_array
FROM   tbl;
```

***If not***, you could cast to a common element type of your choice (`text` would be the safe default):

```
SELECT CASE x
         WHEN 1 THEN ARRAY[x::text]
         WHEN 2 THEN ARRAY[x::text, y::text, z::text]
       END AS my_result_array
FROM   tbl;
```

Or, to make it work for heterogeneous data types, you can use a composite type (row type) and pad with NULL values. Name, number and type of output columns are fixed and have to cover all possible result combinations.

```
CREATE TYPE foo (a int, b text, c date);

SELECT CASE x
         WHEN 1 THEN (x, NULL, NULL)::foo
         WHEN 2 THEN (x, y, z)::foo
       END AS my_result_array
FROM   tbl;
```

Or you could use a document type like `json`, `hstore` or `xml` to contain a variable number of column ...

Note that you get ***one*** result column either way, the workarounds just *contain* a variable payload - which can be decomposed in the next step.

Comment: Thank you very comprehensive!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't since columns selection are static. If you really want to choose columns dynamically based on some condition then consider building a [`dynamic query`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Dynamic SQL can only help with this if `x` is given input parameter, so we can execute a different query depending on it. If `x` is a table column, there is nothing a dynamic query could do. SQL does not allow varying types in the result. That aside, your link is to ecpg of Postgres 9.1. A more useful resource would be plpgsql of the current version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN